# File upload : get absolute path

Tags: vaadin

Can't I get the absolute file path of the selected file from upload component? I am getting the fileName but not the path. Is there any way I can the absolute file path of the uploaded file?

Answer (score 2):

Vaadin Upload uses html tag: `<input type="file">`

For security reasons browsers do not allow this, i.e. JavaScript in browser has no access to the File System!

Referal: [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Comment: Is there a workaround that makes it possible to get the full path ?